# Redirect a subdomain to another IP with nginx

Tags: redirect, nginx, dns, subdomain

This is my problem:

I have a website **mywebsite.tld** and my email address is on another domain, let's say **mywebmail.tld**.

What I want is to create a subdmain **mail.mywebsite.tld** which redirect to **mywebmail.tld** but I want to keep the url **mail.mywebsite.tld**.

I know how to redirect but I don't know how to keep the good url. I also tried with an iframe but it doesn't work with roundcube.

What I have to do with my registar or/and my nginx configuration?

Thank you :)

EDIT : I tried `mail 10800 IN A IP-OF-mywebmail.tld` in my registar but it's like a simple redirection. In fact, the IP of `mywebmail.tld` has a redirection on it... I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: It would be easiest and best to create a DNS entry for `mail.mywebsite.tld` that points to the same IP as `mywebmail.tld`, provided that the server at `mywebmail.tld` responds to that host name. Otherwise you need to set up a proxy...

Comment: @Siguza I just add an A entry like "mail 10800 IN A IP-OF-mywebmail.tld". Now I'm waiting for DNS propagation. I hope it will be good :)